# Auto-configure Hibernate6 with a JsonFormatMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-6.x

Auto-configure Hibernate6 with a JsonFormatMapper that uses the auto-configured Jackson ObjectMapper

When I am adding the definition in application.yml it is working fine

```
hibernate:
  type:
    json_format_mapper: com.xxxx.epm.yyyy.util.JacksonJsonFormatMapperCustom
    # Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
```

Comment: Hello, it's not clear - what is your question?